# static variable in h file causes unused variable error

Tags: objective-c, variables, static

I recently joined a team making an app, and am trying to get the code up and running.

In many .h files, they define static variables, like `static NSString *post = @"post";`, and then reference to them in the .m file. The declaration in the .h file causes an unused variable error. Upon googling this error, it seems that you *cant* define static variable there, they must be extern static, and then redeclared and initiated in the .m file. How are the other members of the team building and successfully running this code?

I thought I would ask here first incase I am missing something stupid.

Thanks

Comment: Go and ask your team, this code seems to be broken by design.

Comment: `unused variable` is not an error, it's a warning. Also, definition is not declaration, you don't seem to know the difference. Furthermore, it **is** possible to define static variables in header files like this.

Comment: H2CO3: It is an error. It is causing the build to fail with 'unused variable'.

Comment: @user2272641 that's because you have `-Werror` on, then.  allprog has the right answer for you - it's rare to want to put `static` *anything* in header files.

Comment: @CarlNorum errors for unused variables are turned off in the build settings though. But youre right, ill ask the others